# Angular Router Navigation doesnt remove previous component css

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-routing

I am new to angular and build two component in my first angular app.
In first component i put a click on button to navigate to second component.

I m using below code for navigation :

```
this.router.navigate(['../secondcomponent/'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

but i can see that second component is having css of component 1. How can i make sure that on each router navigation previous component css will removed and only that component as well as the index.html css should be present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your components should be **encapsulated** : this means that if you declare CSS of a component, it is only for that component.

If this isn't the case, you either :

- declared your styles into a common CSS file
- declared a CSS file as a stylesheet of both components
- Un-encapsulated your components

In all cases, resolving it will resolve your issue. Could you post your code so that we can see what you did ?

Comment: oh yes my bad i have put    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
in both component. Thanks a ton

Comment: No problem, think about marking your question as resolved !